# is_active boolean field in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a series of models, I would like to know the is_active status for each model of data?

models.py:

```
from activatable_model.models import BaseActivatableModel

class Account(BaseActivatableModel):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = 'do_nothing',blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from activatable_model import model_activations_changed

@receiver(model_activations_changed, sender=Account)
def do_something_on_deactivation(sender, instance_ids, is_active, **kwargs):
    if not is_active:
        def delete_user(request, username):
            context = {}

            try:
                u = User.objects.get(username=username)
                u.delete()
                context['msg'] = 'The user is deleted.'       
            except User.DoesNotExist: 
                context['msg'] = 'User does not exist.'
            except Exception as e: 
                context['msg'] = e.message

        for account in Account.objects.filter(id__in=instance_ids):
            def delete_profile(request):
                user = request.user
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully disabled.')
```

I need to get to know that, when the subject_name create it should show the status active if not in-active.Please let me know how to proceed after this steps?

Comment: You `def`ine functions in the `if` and `for` loop?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please make it clear?